# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech returns "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Tags: json, rest, api, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am trying Google Cloud's Text-to-Speech using REST.
It works fine while using [Google's API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/text%20to%20speech/texttospeech/v1beta1/texttospeech.text.synthesize?fields=audioContent&_h=4&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522audioConfig%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522audioEncoding%2522%253A%20%2522MP3%2522%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522input%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522text%2522%253A%20%2522This%20is%20a%20text%20to%20speak%2522%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522voice%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522languageCode%2522%253A%20%2522en-US%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522en-US-Standard-B%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522ssmlGender%2522%253A%20%2522MALE%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&).

But when I try to make a post call, it returns the following error (The API key I'm using has no restrictions):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\r\n \"audioConfig\": {\r\n  \"audioEncoding\": \"MP3\"\r\n },\r\n \"input\": {\r\n  \"text\": \"This is a text to speak\"\r\n },\r\n \"voice\": {\r\n  \"languageCode\": \"en-US\",\r\n  \"name\": \"en-US-Standard-B\"\r\n }\r\n}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\r\n \"audioConfig\": {\r\n  \"audioEncoding\": \"MP3\"\r\n },\r\n \"input\": {\r\n  \"text\": \"This is a text to speak\"\r\n },\r\n \"voice\": {\r\n  \"languageCode\": \"en-US\",\r\n  \"name\": \"en-US-Standard-B\"\r\n }\r\n}' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\r\n \"audioConfig\": {\r\n  \"audioEncoding\": \"MP3\"\r\n },\r\n \"input\": {\r\n  \"text\": \"This is a text to speak\"\r\n },\r\n \"voice\": {\r\n  \"languageCode\": \"en-US\",\r\n  \"name\": \"en-US-Standard-B\"\r\n }\r\n}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\r\n \"audioConfig\": {\r\n  \"audioEncoding\": \"MP3\"\r\n },\r\n \"input\": {\r\n  \"text\": \"This is a text to speak\"\r\n },\r\n \"voice\": {\r\n  \"languageCode\": \"en-US\",\r\n  \"name\": \"en-US-Standard-B\"\r\n }\r\n}' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Request body:

```
{
 "audioConfig": {
  "audioEncoding": "MP3"
 },
 "input": {
  "text": "This is a text to speak"
 },
 "voice": {
  "languageCode": "en-US",
  "name": "en-US-Standard-B"
 }
}
```

Post link: https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?fields=audioContent&key={MY_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [Text-to-Speech Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol#synthesize_audio_from_text)

I successfully did the following POST request:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'text':'This is a text to speak'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-US',
      'name':'en-US-Standard-B'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=MY_KEY" > synthesize-text.txt
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had mistakes in setting headers.
Thanks for the help