# Google TTS Fetch Request - Error 400: "Input type has to be text or SSML"

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, google-text-to-speech

I'm making a React Native app and calling Google's text-to-speech API from the endpoint https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize.

However, when I run my code, I get the following error:
`{"error": {"code": 400, "message": "Input type has to be text or SSML. Maybe the input is empty?", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}`

My code is below:

```
const API_KEY = "...";
const API_URL = `https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=${API_KEY}`;

const speak = async (text) => {
  try {
    console.log("sup");
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        input: {
          text: "Hello world",
        },
        voice: {
          languageCode: "en-US",
          name: "en-US-Wavenet-A",
          ssmlGender: "MALE",
        },
        audioConfig: {
          audioEncoding: "MP3",
        },
      },
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};
```

As you can see, the input is of type text, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Using an SSML input didn't help (I still got the same error message). I made sure that the API key and endpoint are correct, and I tried changing some parameters (like the voice name and the endpoint from v1beta to v1), but to no avail.

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears that your Google text-to-speech input is empty. Could you check whether you are passing input to this API or not?

Comment: Hi Kiran, if you take a look at the body of the fetch request, I've set input to an object containing a string of text. Am I possibly passing this text incorrectly?

Comment: The error message says that there is no input text(text to convert into speech) for google cloud text to speech. You can verify this by using log when you are executing this code.Take a look at these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277949/google-cloud-text-to-speech-returns-invalid-argument) and [link3](https://www.netguru.com/blog/react-native-text-to-speech) also.